# Stored procedure will not display in object explorer?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
USE [MASTER]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
USE [MASTER]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TOTALLY_NEW] @FISCAL_YEAR NVARCHAR(4) AS
BEGIN
PRINT 'HERE'
END
GO
```

---

`select * from master..sysobjects
where name like 'tot%'` <-- returns one row!!!!!!

I've refreshed this list a dozen times..!!
I've tried disconnecting and reconnecting..
I've created all those other SP's listed in the image before.

[image]

Here is a picture with more.
[image]

Comment: Umm, are you sure this is the Programmability node under the master database (and why are you creating all of these user objects in master)? What happens when you highlight Stored Procedures and then show Object Explorer Details? Why is the screen shot conveniently cut off before the spot where dbo.TOTALLY_NEW would have appeared?

Comment: I chopped the photo before the next folder icon...trust me!

Comment: You didn't address my other questions - are you sure this is master, why are you creating user procedures in master, and what do you see in Object Explorer details?

Comment: I'll answer the rest on Monday when I'm back at work.

Comment: I reread your comments.  Not sure why you are implying that I would intentionally cut off the image to make it look like I had an issue.  Anyways I attached a more complete image.  Now how do I check permissions on an object I can't navigate to?

Comment: I wasn't implying that you did it on purpose, just seemed funny that the new procedure was last alphabetically, that's all. Have you tried creating more than one procedure? What happens when you issue `GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON dbo.TOTALLY_NEW TO [<user>];`?

Comment: Still not there, and according to this forum thread, it isn't even possible to hide and SP using permissions......http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=92542

Comment: Okay, WTF? They are under System Stored Procedures!!!!  How in the world did that happen?  Anyways, I was "following the leader",  Methinks moving all this junk out of master would be wise based on yours and other suggestions.

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't be creating user objects in master. The only time I ever do it is when I explicitly want to create a utility procedure that I can call from any database using that database's context, which you have to do on purpose and doesn't happen by accident - so I suspect you inadvertently marked your object as a system procedure. You do this using EXEC sp_MS_marksystemobject (or in older versions by having set EXEC sp_MS_upd_sysobj_category 1 - the latter might work in 2005 with 80 compatibility, not sure).

Comment: Could you put that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per request, converting comment to answer:

Yes, you shouldn't be creating user objects in master. The only time I ever do it is when I explicitly want to create a utility procedure that I can call from any database using that database's context, which you have to do on purpose and doesn't happen by accident - so I suspect you inadvertently marked your object as a system procedure. You do this using EXEC sp_MS_marksystemobject (or in older versions by having set EXEC sp_MS_upd_sysobj_category 1 - the latter might work in 2005 with 80 compatibility, not sure).

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the user you are using has permissions to view stored procedures. I am not 100% on SQL Server which permission this is but I have seen this problem on a few other databases where a user creates a SP, but another user does not have permission to view or list the SPs.

Comment: I've created dozens of sps using this account. I can even execute the sp currently without it visible.

Comment: I agree with Khirok -- I have seen this before and it was a permissions issue (even if you are able to execute the sproc, you might not have permissions to view the code).

Comment: I'm 50% of the IT dept....how could permissions have been changed? How can I review the permissions?  I had the other 50% of the dept try with their log in and same issue.